# React Native Push Notifications not working in Android but works fine on iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-push-notification

I've recently set up push notifications in my React Native app and it's working fine in iOs, but failing to pop up in Android. Here is the function that I'm calling to trigger the notification.

```
function pushNotif(){ 
        PushNotification.localNotification({
                channelId: "specialid", // (required) channelId, if the channel doesn't exist, notification will not trigger.
                title: "hello",
                message: "test message"
        })
}
```

and here is where I configure the push notification above

```
// Must be outside of any component LifeCycle (such as `componentDidMount`).
PushNotification.configure({
   // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
   onRegister: function (token) {
   console.log("TOKEN:", token);
    },

    // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
    onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);     
    // process the notification   
    // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
            },
    // (optional) Called when Registered Action is pressed and invokeApp is false, if true onNotification will be called (Android)
    onAction: function (notification) {
        console.log("ACTION:", notification.action);
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
            // process the action
            },
            // (optional) Called when the user fails to register for remote notifications. Typically occurs when APNS is having issues, or the device is a simulator. (iOS)
     onRegistrationError: function(err) {
           console.error(err.message, err);
            },
     // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
            permissions: {
                alert: true,
                badge: true,
                sound: true,
            },
     // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
            // default: true
            popInitialNotification: true,
            /**
             * (optional) default: true
             * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
             * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
             * - if you are not using remote notification or do not have Firebase installed, use this:
             *     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
             */
            requestPermissions: true,
            });
```

As I said it's working fine on iOS, and when I remove the channelId (which I know is required for android) I get this message...
`No Channel ID Passed. Notification may not work`

This leads me to believe it's being configured somehow but not fully.

Here are the rest of my configuration files after following this: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

In `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" // default: "21.1.0"
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
             <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="false"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
...
```

In `android/app/src/main/java/com/{app_name}/MainActivity.java`

```
...
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.content.Intent;



public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
      super.onNewIntent(intent);
  }
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "cjcChatApp";
  }
}
```

How can I get this to work on Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you forgot for create chanel, you can try this :

```js
function pushNotif(){
  PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: "specialid", // (required)
      channelName: "Special messasge", // (required)
      channelDescription: "Notification for special message", // (optional) default: undefined.
      importance: 4, // (optional) default: 4. Int value of the Android notification importance
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration patten if true.
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
  );
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    channelId:'specialid', //his must be same with channelid in createchannel
    title:'hello',
    message:'test message'
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case

`react-native-push-notification` not working in **android 12**

so I added some lines in

`node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java`

change this line

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationID, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        }
        else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```